# Sidebar scroll affected by content behind

Tags: html, css

I created a sidebar with page content as follows ([Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4fqc6vzu/7/)):

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... More content</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#sidebar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;   
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;     
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.90; /* Used opacity to show content behind */
}
```

I need the sidebar do fill entire screen and scroll vertically if sidebar content is big ...

But I don't want the sidebar do scroll if content behind is big ...

In the example there is Y scroll because content behind is big even if sidebar's content is not.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Some likely this:

```css
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.90;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ... More content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So you need to use jQuery, add class active to sidebar #sidebar.active{height: 100vh;overflow-y: auto;} and if sidebar has class active give css to body overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: Can't this be done by adding a div wrapping the sidebar and the content instead of using body?